# Java Socket programming push servlet - Servlet is not getting initialised after deploying it to the server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, push-notification

Any one can help on this?. Locally it is working without any issue. After the application deployment to the server, it is not initialising the push servlet, throwing below exception.

> 05-Dec-2017 13:26:31.898 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Push Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current
>   chain does not support asynchronous operations.   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1621)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1037)

Thanks,
Abees

Comment: Download the following jars and add it to your WEB-INF/lib directory:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Download the following jar and add it to the your WEB-INF/lib directory

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar

http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2.zip

IF you are using maven make sure you have the dependency for jstl artifact:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and also restart your server and check again..

Comment: All the dependencies are there but it is working in local . Issue is only with the server